# Make mongo query in spring where Document contain array

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

I am using spring and mongo for API developemt with the following document structure:

```
Document-1
myId:1
array:['abc','jkl','xyz']

Document-2
myId:3
array:['qwe','mnp','xyz']

Document-3
myId:3
array:['ped','abc','xyz']

My url : localhost:8080/array=xyz
expected : document-1,document-2,document-3

My url: localhost:8080/array=xyz,abc
exoected: document-1,document-3
```

In short I want all the documents in result which contains all the comma separated `array` variable.

Is there ary inbuild support that spring provides for this like @Query annotation?

Or How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You essentially want to use the **[`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/)** operator to get the desired results. In the mongo shell, the following operation will bring the documents:

**Populate test collection**

```
db.test.insert([
    {
        _id: 1,
        myId: 1,
        array: ['abc','jkl','xyz']
    },
    {
        _id: 2,
        myId: 3,
        array: ['qwe','mnp','xyz']
    },
    {
        _id: 3,
        myId: 3,
        array:['ped','abc','xyz']
    }
])
```

**Run operations**

```
> db.test.find({"array": { "$all": ["xyz"] }})
{ "_id" : 1, "myId" : 1, "array" : [ "abc", "jkl", "xyz" ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "myId" : 3, "array" : [ "qwe", "mnp", "xyz" ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "myId" : 3, "array" : [ "ped", "abc", "xyz" ] }

> db.test.find({"array": { "$all": ["abc", "xyz"] }})
{ "_id" : 1, "myId" : 1, "array" : [ "abc", "jkl", "xyz" ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "myId" : 3, "array" : [ "ped", "abc", "xyz" ] }
```

As with the `@Query` annotation in Spring Data MongoDB, I haven't tested this but you may want to try the following custom query implementation example

```
@Document(collection="test")
class Test {
    int myId;
    String[] array;
}

public interface TestRepository extends MongoRepository<Test, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "{ 'array' : {$all : [?0] }}")
    public List<Test> findAnyOfTheseValues(String[] arrayValues);
}
```

If the above doesn't work for you, you may want to create a custom interface and your implementation class to execute the custom query. For example, create an interface with a name that appends Custom:

```
public interface TestRepositoryCustom {
    public List<Test> findAnyOfTheseValues(String[] arrayValues); 
}
```

Modify the `TestRepository` and add the `TestRepositoryCustom` interface to be extended:

```
@Repository
public interface TestRepository extends TestRepositoryCustom, MongoRepository {

}
```

Create your implementation class to implement the methods defined in `TestRepositoryCustom` interface.

```
public class TestRepositoryImpl implements TestRepositoryCustom {

    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Override
    public List<Test> findAnyOfTheseValues(String[] arrayValues) {
        return mongoTemplate.find(
            Query.query(Criteria.where("array").all(arrayValues)), Test.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tested the @Query, but it is not working the way it has to be. The result I got for localhost:8080/array=abc,xyz. It is giving only the documents that has "array":["abc","xyz"] only. Even the order matters. And not giving the documents that contain array:["abc","xyz","ped"].Testing the second solution

Comment: thanks, great answer, but what about case insensitive, is it possible? +1

Comment: I tested the accepted answer and it doesn't work properly with the Spring Repository. The query generated by that method looks like: { "tags" : { "$all" : [["tag1"]] } } it requires a minimal adjustment
```java
@Query(value = "{ 'tags' : {$all : ?0 }}")
List<Sampling> findWithTags(String[] arrayValues);
```
to generate a query like { "tags" : { "$all" : ["tag1"] } }

Comment: is that `where.all` or `where.in` ?